# Browser not supported with Firebase on localhost?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm consistently getting an error, `This browser is not supported.` in the console when working on a Firebase application on my local machine.  At current, the error is preventing authentication, but with a bit more code I can access the database.

I've torn down my app to the basic Javascript provided by Firebase:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<sic>",
    authDomain: "<sic>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<sic>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<sic>.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

There is no other Javascript being loaded (no, not even jQuery).  If I use `firebase deploy` and look at the live site, no error.

If it matters, I'm using Chrome 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit), using Jekyll to serve the site off my local machine, and have tried `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and `local.iig-dev.com` (something from my work that resolves to localhost).  All to no avail.

Comment: Hey Jack, try to check your browser settings in case you have restricted 3rd party cookies. You should typically choose the default settings. A good idea would be to try your test app in a different device or browser. This will give you clues on whether this is an issue with your browser or with your configurations. Firebase v3 auth relies on web storage to function properly. You need to ensure that these are enabled.

Comment: @bojeil It appears you are correct!  I have had that set FOREVER.  If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to check your browser settings in case you have restricted 3rd party cookies. You should typically choose the default settings.